# How can I make a hover in a input number of a class and change it's -webkit-inner-spin-button opacity turns to 1?

Tags: html, css

It is possible?
This is what I tried, but doesn't work:

```css
.myClass input[type=range]:hover > .myClass input[type=range]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
  opacity: 0;
}

.myClass input[type=range]:hover > input[type=range]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <input type="number" value="1">
</div>
```

Here is the problem, the spin-buttons are cutting the numbers of the input even if it's opacity is 0:

[image: spin-buttons cutting the numbers of the input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myClass > input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
            display: none;
        }
        .myClass > input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myClass">
        <input type="number" value="1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, `::-webkit-inner-spin-button` isn't supported by Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I suggest you to use `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0`, to remove those buttons completely on hover, otherwise they stay there and if user click on them, they will respond.

Comment: it need to happens when the input is hovered

Comment: Yeah, it works, but the spin-button still there. I need to remove it and sho on hover, or it will stay cuttin the number [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpTll.png)

Comment: show, even if its opacity is 0, the spin-buttons still there

Comment: That is what I warned you about `opacity`. Check it out. I am sure this code will solve your problem